# Undefined exception when running meteor subscribe from angular

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

My angular controller looks like this:

```
angular.module("campos").controller("HomeCtrl", ['$scope', '$meteor', '$rootScope', '$state', '$modal',
    function ($scope, $meteor, $rootScope, $state, $modal) {
    // $scope.users = $meteor.collection(Meteor.users, false).subscribe('users');

    $meteor.autorun($scope, function () {
        $scope.$meteorSubscribe('myOrgnization', 'crown').then(function () {
                $scope.organization.forEach(function (org) {
                    console.log(org._id);
                });
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    });

    $scope.organization = $meteor.collection(function(){
        return Organizations.find({});
    });
}
```

]);

The server code looks like :

```
Meteor.publish('myOrgnization', function(org){
    return Organizations.find({
        'code' : org
    });
});
```

The client controller finished properly, from the console I can get the the record id properly. However, I got an exception thrown out:

```
 TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at http://localhost:8026/packages/urigo_angular.js?de756130fe1ce5aaa41d3967997c1b2090bcdd1b:390:12
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:8026/packages/underscore.js?46eaedbdeb6e71c82af1b16f51c7da4127d6f285:149:11)
    at diffArray (http://localhost:8026/packages/urigo_angular.js?de756130fe1ce5aaa41d3967997c1b2090bcdd1b:388:5)
    at updateCollection (http://localhost:8026/packages/urigo_angular.js?de756130fe1ce5aaa41d3967997c1b2090bcdd1b:1310:3)
    at http://localhost:8026/packages/urigo_angular.js?de756130fe1ce5aaa41d3967997c1b2090bcdd1b:1154:11
    at http://localhost:8026/packages/angular_angular.js?feeaf4750c9fd3ceafa9f712f99a21ee6fef9b41:17819:31
    at completeOutstandingRequest (http://localhost:8026/packages/angular_angular.js?feeaf4750c9fd3ceafa9f712f99a21ee6fef9b41:5529:10)
    at http://localhost:8026/packages/angular_angular.js?feeaf4750c9fd3ceafa9f712f99a21ee6fef9b41:5806:7
home.ng.js:8 dPmZoCeJ9YbKxKA4u
```

It seems coming from angular defer, but I think I am following the subscribe syntax properly ? even I change it to use $meter.subscribe, it throws the same exception.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the $scope collection after the promise returns:

```
    $scope.$meteorSubscribe('myOrgnization', 'crown').then(function () {
        $scope.organization = $scope.$meteorCollection(function(){
            return Organizations.find({});
        });
    });
```

I would also suggest passing an object for your publish arguments:

```
$scope.$meteorSubscribe('myOrginization', {arg1: 'crown'}).then(...)
```

Then of course on the server you would get:

```
Meteor.publish('myOrgnization', function(org){
    return Organizations.find({
        'code' : org.arg1
    });
});
```

Comment: I would also like to add that the $meteor.autorun is only needed if you have a $scope variable within it that you will be changing. Otherwise just leave that part out.